# blur event not working as expected with dynamically created inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table which can have some dinamically created inputs, so the user can throw in some values and make some calculations:

```
<table>
   <thead>...</thead>
   <tbody>
     <tr>
        <td>Info</td>
        <td><input class="inputsTable"/></td>
        <td><input class="inputsTable"/></td>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

When the user inputs a value and the blur event occurs, the system would do some calculations. I had the "multiple blur events firing" problem and i solved like this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {        
        $(".inputsTable").mask("#.##0,00", { reverse: true });
        //setting up masks
    });

    let isBound = false;
    $('.inputsTable').on('input propertychange paste', function () {
        if (!isBound) {
            isBound = true;
            $(this).on('blur', function () {
                alert($(this).val());
            });
        }
    });

</script>
```

It works for the first input. If i try to fire the blur event from the second input, it won't work. And if i reset the isBound variable:

```
$('.inputsTable').on('input propertychange paste', function () {
            if (!isBound) {
                isBound = true;
                $(this).on('blur', function () {
                    alert($(this).val());
                    isBound = false;
                });
            }
        });
```

Sometimes it works, but sometimes it will fire multiple times. How can i solve this?

Comment: Don't create event bindings in other event bindings.  Rather take a look at making delegate event bindings that only work under your desired conditions. [jQuery Learn Delegate Event Bindings](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: I've changed to a delegate event binding but it still keeps firing multiple times:

$('.inputsTable').on('blur', function (event) {
        alert(this.value);
        return false;//event.stopProppagation or event.preventDefault didn't work
    });

Comment: That's not a delegate.  `$(parentSelector).on(event, childSelector, eventHandler)` is a delegate, as that link explains in detail.  The `childSelector` is the part that should be conditionally true

Comment: Tried with the parent and child selector, but no luck:

$('td').on('blur', '.inputsTable', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert(this.value);
    });

Comment: fired multiple times because of on input event , where it is getting triggered for each character entered in input and also because of unconditional blur

Answer (score 1):

Try this if it works. If you are inserting or appending inputs dynamic then you should use `document` to reload the DOM.

```
 $(document).on('.inputsTable','input propertychange paste', function () {
        if (!isBound) {
            isBound = true;
            $(this).on('blur', function () {
                alert($(this).val());
                isBound = false;
            });
        }
    });
```

OR

```
 $(document).on('.inputsTable','input propertychange paste', function () {
         $(this).on('blur', function () {
            alert($(this).val());
         });
    });
```

But it would be fine if you upload the full code.